# Correct way to design Mongo Schema w.r.t time complexity

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My use case is as follows.

I need to maintain purchase history of users w.r.t products in MongoDB. I am having trouble in selecting the correct schema design w.r.t time complexity.

```
>db: username
>>collection product 1: single document with product 1 details

>>collection product 2: single document with product 2 details

>>collection product 3: single document with product 3 details
--------------------------------------------------------------

>db: username
>>collection products: multiple documents
>>>document product 1: product 1 details

>>>document product 2: product 2 details

>>>document product 3: product 3 details
```

Among the above 2 designs, which one is efficient for querying and getting the product information?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your design 1 is storing one product per collection and your design 2 is storing all products in same collection? If so, design 1 does not seems sensible to me as it will likely introduce a lot of unnecessary complexity in composing queries.

Comment: Yes @ray your understanding of my question is correct. So you are suggesting to go with design 2 to avoid complexity?

Comment: Yes. To be more clear, it is the complexity on composing query,  not time complexity. MongoDB performance questions usually requires far more context than a usual stackoverflow question holds, but for your case, design 1 just seems obviously bad for your future queries, as you will need much more effort to handle the collection name, if a `$lookup` operation is likely to be used.